# Gulp Task: CleanCSS and Paths

Tags: css, gulp, minify, gulp-clean-css

I've created a task with Gulp that is supposed to:

1. Join multiple CSS files;
2. Minify + remove unnecessary CSS;
3. Fix paths for `url()` directives and others;
4. Generate source maps;

My current code for this is:

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    concat      = require("gulp-concat"),
    cleanCSS    = require("gulp-clean-css"),
    sourcemaps  = require("gulp-sourcemaps");

var styleList = [
    "Resources/Include/ionicons/css/ionicons.css",
    "Resources/base.css",
    "Resources/extra.css",
];

gulp.task("deploy-css", function() {
    gulp.src(styleList)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(concat("style.min.css"))
    .pipe(cleanCSS({
            debug: true, 
            compatibility: "ie8", 
            keepSpecialComments : 0,
            target: "Resources/",
            relativeTo: "Resources/"
        })
    )
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("Resources/"))
});
```

**`url()` path example**, taken from file `Resources/Include/ionicons/css/ionicons.css`:

```
@font-face { font-family: "Ionicons"; src: url("../fonts/ionicons.eot?v=2.0.0");
```

**This is my current file structure**:

```
./Resources/style.min.css // -> Final processed file
./Resources/base.css
./Resources/extras.css
./Resources/Include/ // -> Original CSS files with URL (installed via Bower)
```

**Test folder**: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2333896/gulp-path-test.zip (install and then run with `gulp deploy-css`).

Almost everything works as expected, except for when CSS files include references to images or fonts using the `url()` option. After running the task (and `style.min.css` created) those references are broken - no change was made to the paths found on the original CSS files.

Isn't `cleanCSS` supposed to check where the referenced files are and fix the paths automatically? Aren't the options `target` and `relativeTo` used to control that?

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: More info needed. What's the value of `styleList`? What do your `url()` paths looks like before processing? What should they look like after processing? Where are the references resources located? You need to  provide a [mcve].

Comment: @SvenSchoenung check my edit.

Comment: Not reproducible. Running your example yields `src:url(Include/ionicons/fonts/ionicons.eot?v=2.0.0)`.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung I just added a minimal test setup so you can compare with yours / test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue, my main problems were a misplaced `concat` operation breaking `gulp-clean-css` rebase feature and wrong `target` and `relativeTo` options. Apparently I didn't think much about the previous workflow.

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    concat      = require("gulp-concat"),
    cleanCSS    = require("gulp-clean-css"),
    sourcemaps  = require("gulp-sourcemaps");

var styleList = [
    "Resources/Include/ionicons/css/ionicons.css",
    "Resources/base.css",
    "Resources/extra.css",
    "Resources/Include/teste/base.css"
];

gulp.task("deploy-css", function() {
    gulp.src(styleList)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(cleanCSS({
            compatibility: "ie8", 
            keepSpecialComments : 0,
            target: "Resources",
            relativeTo: ""
        })
    )
    .pipe(concat("style.min.css", {newLine: ""}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("Resources"))
});
```

This new workflow works as:

1. Optimize all individual CSS files - including rebasing urls;
2. Contact individual optimized files into the final file - (note `newLine: ""` avoids line breaks in the file);
3. Write the file.